# How can I pass a CSS selector with IDs or class names in R html_nodes?

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to extract the names of parliament members from the homepage of the German parliament, however, regardless which css selector or xpath I'm trying it returns nothing.

https://www.bundestag.de/ausschuesse/a11#

[image: Screenshot]

```
#names <- landing_page_AS %>%
#html_nodes("main > div") %>% 
#extract2(7) %>%
#html_nodes("h3") %>%
#html_text()

names <- landing_page_AS %>% 
html_nodes(".bt-teaser-person-text h3") %>%
#html_nodes(xpath = "//*[(@id = "bt-collapse-538348")]//h3") %>%
#html_nodes(xpath = "//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), 
concat( " ", "bt-teaser-person-text", " " ))]//h3") %>% 
html_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the list of names from German parliament website using selenium.  The problem could be that the server denies access to your bot without using a headless browser.

If you use selenium, this is the code and xpath you could use, which worked for me :

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"your_webdriver_address", chrome_options = chrome_options)

#OPEN NEW BROWSER
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

driver.get('https://www.bundestag.de/en/members')

button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'icon-list-bullet')]")
button = button[0]
button.click()
time.sleep(3)
GE_MEMBERS_NAMES = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'bt-teaser-person-text')]/h3")

for item in GE_MEMBERS_NAMES:
    name = item.text
    print (name)
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) (don't hesitate to upvote it or accept the answer, if you felt it was helpful) :)